# Using fmincon() in blackbox optimization

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, black-box

I have a blackbox optimization problem, meaning, I have a shared-object file that I can call from within a `Matlab` function supplying it with input variable `x` and I can get the objective value `obj` as well as constraint-violations `cv`. The following can be noted :

1. `x` is a vector of known length with known bounds
2. `obj` is a scalar value
3. `cv` is a vector of known length

There is no information available on type of constraints. Can use `fmincon` to solve this optimization problem.

P.S : I already have a good starting point.

Comment: I think you can. However note that `fmincon` will do finite differences. `fmincon` really assumes your functions are smooth, exact and cheap to evaluate. If your evaluations are expensive you may want to use a derivative free method instead.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Actually, my shared-lib function also returns gradients. Can I use `nonlcon` option?

Comment: Exact gradients will help `fmincon` a lot.